# Why does sine law have an ambigious case, but cosine law doesn't?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, proof-explanation

I know that in q1 and q2 (where a triangle angles would lie) sine supplementary values give the same answer. However, this logic cant prove the question because in one of the cases where there is only one triangle (not 90-degree case), it could give two different values even though it can't since the supplementary doesn't count. I am stuck on this and am wondering how to prove that sine ambiguous case exists and cosine law doesn't have one while using basic math (high school level).

Comment: What are q1 and q2?

Comment: @peterwhy I think it's the first and second quadrants of the Cartesian plane.

Comment: To check whether ambiguous case exists also depends on what information about the triangle is given.

Answer (score 3):

On the interval $[0, \pi)$, $\cos(x)$ is injective but $\sin(x)$ is not. Thus, if you know sides $a$ and $b$, and angle $A$, you can use the sine law to find $\sin(B)$ and $\sin(C)$, but not the angles themselves.

On the other hand, if you know $\cos(\theta)$, you know $\theta$.

Comment: OP may not know the jargon “injective”.  Perhaps mention that “$\sin x$ is not injective” just means that perhaps $\sin a = \sin b$ even when $a\ne b$?

Comment: just in case you find this useful, you can use "\sin x" to write $\sin x$

Answer (score 2):

I'm pitching this answer at what I think is a high school level.

[image]

If you can apply the cosine law of $c^2=a^2+b^2-2abcos(\angle C)$, and are solving for $c$, then you must have all the information of SAS and the triangle is fully specified.

If you have information to apply the sine law, it is often a situation such as knowing $a,b, \angle A$ in the figure. Imagine if you pivot $CB$ about $C$, for some fixed value of $\angle A$ there is a larger acute triangle that works, and a smaller obtuse one. The blue and red segments in the picture below illustrate the idea. They are different triangles but $sin(\angle B)$ is the same.

[image]